# How to I get my JSP code to run when I refresh my page

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP page that is a keypad emulator, like a keypad on a security door.

When the page loads the JSP makes a call to a java file that checks a txt document to see if the door is locked or not. If it is locked the keypad should not work, else if it is unlocked the keypad should be functional.

This text document is edited with a separate Java application and all that works. However when I load my site up, it makes the calls and correctly functions based on the contents of the text file at run time.

The problem is that when I use the Java application to edit the text file, while the site is running, and then hit refresh it continues in the state that it was in when the page was originally ran.

What I want to know is how do I re-execute the JSP portion of the page on page refresh... See if I change the content of the text file to unlocked and hit refresh the page should act as if it was unlocked, and if I then change it to lock and refresh, the page should act as if the keypad is locked. This is for a homework assignment so the requirements are not negotiable.

Thank you in advanced for any and all help.

Edit* Never mind I figured it out... It was doing it, I just had a minor syntactical error... used ....equals("unlocked") instead of ...equals("unlock")... duh... lol.

Comment: I'm just going to say that any school using JSP as homework is beyond cruel.

Comment: Well it is a J2EE class... :P

Answer (score 1):

The JSP should re-execute everytime it's hit.  Are you sure it's not a problem with the Java code that reads the file?  Can you debug/log values in the Java code to make sure it's doing what's expected?

Otherwise, you could try explicitly setting the cache-control header to make sure that there's no caching going on.

Comment: +1 for the cache check. If the JSP is being told to cache pages, it won't bother re-rendering the page from scratch until the cache times out.

Comment: Thank you yes it was... That is why this was such a vexing problem... I couldn't for the life of me figure this out.. I coded the Java class a couple of days ago so forgot to look at that when I debugged.

Comment: I had thought that I had inadvertently changed something in my IDE or that there was something that I had to change that might have been on by default. Or if I had missed something about how JSP worked, as I was sure that it should execute the code on refresh. I know ultimately it was a stupid question. But this is how we learn.

Comment: Tell your professor the proper way to handle this would be client side via an ajax call at each attempt at use of the lock.